# How to share excluded directories?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We have some custom directories with cache? that should be gitignored and ignored by idea. How to share excluded directories for all project developers with git?

Problem is: how to store idea config about excluded directories - the directories that should not be indexed by idea. (Example for webstorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html)

These excluded directories should be gitignored (it's easy) and I want to store in git idea configuration about this exclusion.

## UPDATE

Forget about gitignore :) Just how to store idea directory exclusion in some file in any vcs?

Comment: If you want to share some directories **for all project developers with git** why did you ignore them? Unignore, add, commit, push. If you want to continue ignoring them `git` doesn't have means to share ignored files; use tools outside of git; for example, `rsync`.

Comment: See my tentative answer. I suspect there is more detail to your problem that you have not explained. Specifically why they "should be gitignored" yet shared with git (a contradiction).

Comment: You can't do that. Git stores *commits* and commits store files with names. The names are the names in the commit; the contents are those in the commit; the files are either there, or they are not there. Checking out that commit extracts those files, which are now tracked, not ignored. The usual approach to handling this contradiction is to have *template* files that are committed, not ignored. The "set me up" command is now two parts: clone the repository, then copy the template into place. The in-place copies *are* ignored.

Comment: Forget about gitignore :) Just how to store idea directory exclusion?

Answer (score 0):

This is a contradiction:

- "share excluded directories for all project developers **with git**"
- "that should be **gitignored**"

If you want to share them "with git", remove them from `.gitignore`, add and commit them.

You can use Intellij Idea's project configuration to have it ignore those directories, and commit those config files if you want them shared. See JetBrains' [How to manage projects under Version Control Systems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) for more info.

You might also want to look into JetBrains' *Settings Repository* feature.

Comment: Sorry. I want to gitignore (it's easy)? exclude from indexing and store this exclusion in git.

Comment: exactly. that’s what i’m saying in my answer re Idea’s project config. I’ll make it more explicit

Comment: "You can use Intellij Idea's project configuration to have it ignore those directories, and commit those config files if you want them shared"

It stores inside .idea in .iml files with other user-specific settings. It's not handy to store whole .iml file.

Comment: added a link for you. If none of these work for you, you need to consider whether you're asking for something that doesn't make sense.